# Setting upi a proxy using nginx

Tags: nginx, proxy

I'm trying to setup of proxy using nginx, but it redirects rather than proxy it (at least that's what it looks like). My virtual host config:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name proxy.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass              http://thepiratebay.se/;
        proxy_redirect          off;
        proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        client_max_body_size    10m;
        client_body_buffer_size 128k;
        proxy_connect_timeout   90;
        proxy_send_timeout      90;
        proxy_read_timeout      90;
        proxy_buffers           32 4k;
    }
}
```

Did I screw up somewhere?

The output of the `cURL request to my proxy`:

```
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.13.1.0 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.2.2
> Host: proxy.pieterhordijk.com
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Server: nginx
< Date: Sat, 19 May 2012 00:27:35 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Connection: keep-alive
< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.1
< Location: http://thepiratebay.se/
< Content-Length: 0
<
```

Comment: Where is the client being redirected to?

Comment: `http://thepiratebay.se/`

Comment: Can you paste the output of `curl -v http://proxy.example.com` to determine whether this is an HTTP redirect or something else.

Comment: @mgorven edited my question. It does a `301`.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably the proxied site which is sending a redirect (which nginx simply passes on to the client). You want to set [`proxy_redirect`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_redirect) to `default` so that nginx modifies the redirect appropriately.

**Edit**: `proxy_redirect default` is supposed to handle this situation, but it's not for some reason. Try the following config:

```
proxy_redirect http://thepiratebay.se/ /;
```

Comment: There is not `on` directive for `proxy_redirect`

Comment: Apologies, that should be `default`.

Comment: Results in the same thing (e.g. a redirect) :(

Comment: Edited with another suggestion.